# Full Screen Width not used

Tags: support

Superuser does not use full width of my screen in browser.

My questions are small in the middle, need to be scrolled while there is much border left and right.

Comment: What device, operating system and browser are you using? Please be specific and include version information. [Edit] the question to include this essential information.

Comment: A screen shot would also help us understand your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: Are you at 100% zoom?

Answer (score 3):

That's by design.  The left and right columns are fixed width.  The main column in the middle has a maximum width and two minimum widths.

If the window is wider than the maximum for the three columns, you get blank padding on the sides.  If the window is narrower, the main column in the center will shrink and wrap down to its first minimum width.  Shrinking the window width beyond that will eliminate the right column.  If you shrink the window enough, the left column will also disappear.  If the width is reduced more, the middle column will shrink to its absolute minimum width, beyond which the window width can't be reduced.

What you're seeing is just the site's design.

Comment: Whether it's by design or not, the fact is that it's a highly annoying state of affairs to many, and on many websites that follow this unfortunate path, there are user interventions possible, principally the use of user-written CSS rules. A very few sites also have user-choosable site themes, some of which avoid having all the site content crammed into the middle of the screen. It seems like we have here a deliberate avoidance of answering the actual point of this question: WHY must there be a "maximimum width" on this (and other) Stack Exchange sites, and can anything be done about it?

Comment: @kreemoweet, I agree.  I didn't design the site and don't like that aspect either.  The minimums are useful, but the maximum wastes available screen space.  That said, I'm not sure there's a good, simple alternative without major redesign.  The main column would become difficult to read if it was too much wider.  It is hard to read an extremely wide column of text (which is why periodicals use multiple columns).  If you have a solution, please post it.  It is sure to be a popular post.